# Resolution problem

Tags: 14.04, display-resolution

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu. I installed the latest Ubuntu LTS 14.04.3 over Virrtualbox version 5.0.12. The problem is I cannot get proper resolution. It is just 800x600 default and I want to set it to 1920x1024 but am not able to do so. The resolution option in display setting is disabled. It might be some basic setting but since I am new I don't know. Can somebody help me out? I also don't see auto resize Guest Display as active in view settings..

Comment: Have you installed the [VirtualBox extension pack?](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#intro-installing)

Answer (score 0):

When running your Ubuntu in VirtualBox, click above on **Devices** and then click on **Insert Guest Additions CD image**

Guest Additions improve guest OS stability and performance.

More informations can be found at: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html

I recommend to install VirtualBox Extension Pack (it contains lot of drivers) found at: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

**Extension pack include**:

- The virtual USB 2.0 (EHCI) device
- The virtual USB 3.0 (xHCI) device
- VirtualBox Remote Desktop Protocol (VRDP) support
- Host webcam passthrough
- Intel PXE boot ROM
- Experimental support for PCI passthrough on Linux hosts
- Disk image encryption with AES algorithm